# PCA Biplot variable label customization

Tags: r, ggplot2, factoextra, factominer

I am trying to make PCA biplot by using follwoing code from the given data.
In the data there are 4 type of genotypes, belongs to 4 type of species and 4 types of variables were evaluated (SPAD, PN, Y(II), DMC) under 2 type of conditions 1= control, 2=Stress.
I successfully make the PCA biplot as shown in picture
But I am havng trouble with variable labels shown alongwith the arrows. I want to convert the #1 and #2 into SUPERCRIPT CT and HS or I want to keep the original name for example "Y(II)" but in the grpah it always convert to "Y.II.".
Also I want to change the color of the individual text as they are shown in Parameter legends and also keep the SPecies legend color to differentiate.
[image]

```
pca <- PCA(data.frame(data[,-2], row.names = 1), ncp=7, graph = TRUE, scale.unit = TRUE)

SPAD <- "Chlorophyll Index" 
IRGA <- "Gas exchange"
CF <- "Chlorophyll fluorescence"
ag <- "Morphological traits"
traits <- factor(c(SPAD,IRGA,CF,ag,SPAD, IRGA,CF,ag))

fviz_pca_biplot(pca, 
                geom.ind = c("point","text"),
                pointshape = 21,
                pointsize = 2.5,
                fill.ind = data$Species,
                col.ind = "black",
                col.var = traits,
                legend.title = list(fill = "Species", color = "Parameters"),
                repel = TRUE )+ 
  ggpubr::fill_palette("cosmic")+ # Indiviual fill color
  ggpubr::color_palette(c("brown", "purple", "red","blue")) +  # Variable colors
  theme_gray() + 
  theme(legend.position = "right", 
        legend.text = element_text(face="italic"),
        plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0),
        legend.key.size = unit(0.5, 'cm'),
        legend.background = element_rect(fill='transparent'),
        panel.background = element_rect(colour = "grey30")) +
  labs(title = "", x= "PC1 (62.56%)", y= "PC2 (29.10%)", 
       caption = "*1: Control , 2: Heat stress")
```

| Genotype | Species | SPAD1 | Pn1 | Y(II)1 | DMC1 | SPAD2 | Pn2 | Y(II)2 | DMC2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BEL | sp1 | 0.6 | 14.38 | 0.25 | 0.21 | 1.64 | 16.5 | 0.29 | -0.4 |
| BGB003 | sp2 | -0.24 | 14.87 | 0.2 | -1.24 | -0.33 | 16.63 | 0.27 | -1.24 |
| BGB008 | sp2 | -0.54 | 11.92 | 0.14 | -1.24 | -0.37 | 12.6 | 0.15 | -0.72 |
| BGB083 | sp3 | -1.18 | 6.61 | 0.13 | 0.74 | -0.04 | 5.41 | 0.16 | 0.63 |
| BGB086 | sp3 | -0.89 | 9.05 | 0.19 | -0.53 | -0.33 | 11.2 | 0.17 | -0.28 |
| BGB088 | sp4 | -0.4 | 8.75 | 0.15 | -0.39 | 0.28 | 12.36 | 0.22 | -0.6 |
| BGB089 | sp4 | -0.52 | 9.86 | 0.2 | -0.05 | 0.47 | 11.06 | 0.19 | -0.44 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variables are stored in the row names of your `pca` object. You can edit them to get the plot you desire. In particular you can change e.g. `DMC1` to `DMC^1` and so on, to tell `ggplot2` you want to use superscript:

```r
pca$var <- lapply(pca$var, \(d) {
    # Replace Y.II. with Y(II)
    rownames(d) <- gsub("\\.II\\.", "(II)", rownames(d))
    # Replace e.g. DMC1 with DMC^1
    rownames(d) <- gsub("(1|2)$", "^\\1", rownames(d))
    d
})
```

When drawing your plot, make sure to add `parse = TRUE`, so it knows that `DMC^1` should be treated as superscript.

```r
fviz_pca_biplot(pca,
    geom.ind = c("point", "text"),
    pointshape = 21,
    pointsize = 2.5,
    fill.ind = data$Species,
    col.ind = "black",
    col.var = traits,
    legend.title = list(fill = "Species", color = "Parameters"),
    repel = TRUE,
    parse = TRUE # this is important
) # + all your theme code goes here
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer @SamR . I have one more question, what if I need to add Symbol instead of "Y" such as phi, Sigma or anyother greek symbol??

Comment: With relatively recently versions of R you should just be able to enter `"φ"`, `"σ"`, etc. directly in the code